# $.ajax error handling in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

Hi I am working with jquery form post. When I post the form, it is working fine in IE, but not working with Chrome. 
I put the code here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#signup').submit(function(){

        var username    = $('#username').val();
        var password    = $('#password').val();
        var cpassword   = $('#cpassword').val();
        var email       = $('#email').val();
        if(password != cpassword){
            alert("Passwords are not equal");
            $('#cpassword').css('border','1px solid red');
        }else{
             $.ajax({
                type    :'post',

                url     :'http://localhost/tmc/includes/ajax-signup.php',

                data    :({password:password,username:username,email:email}),

                success : function(msg){
                    alert(msg);

                },                  
            });
        }
        //$("#submit").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean in this case? Do you get an error in Chrome's console? Perhaps the problem is that you never cancel the default submit event - try adding `return false;` as the last line of your submit handler (where you've currently got the commented out `.hide()` statement).

Comment: Is your page designed to only work on localhost ? Are you testing with both browsers on localhost ?

Comment: try to  type:'POST', instead of type :'post',

Comment: Just note, you'll save yourself a lot of hassle in the future if you use relative URLs for functions like this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this :

```
$(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                alert('Time out error.');
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                alert('Ajax request aborted.');
            } else {
                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Just make the ajax call now, and you will get the appropriate alert on any error you get!
Also, there's a plus point in using it. You don't need need to write `error` method for any ajax call again. It acts as a ***global ajax error handler*** using [ajaxSetup()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/).

Also, one more thing I want to mention that just remove the extra `comma` in your ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost/tmc/includes/ajax-signup.php',
    data: ({
        password: password,
        username: username,
        email: email
    }),
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg);
    } //,  <---- remove this extra comma, no need of it
});
```

Comment: it says that not connected verify network. what is the solution for it

Comment: Try to modify the click event like this: `$('#signup').submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); // Your code goes here... });`

Answer (score 0):

Add `id='submit'` to your submit button and try call like this:

```
    $('#submit').click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        var username    = $('#username').val();
        var password    = $('#password').val();
        var cpassword   = $('#cpassword').val();
        var email       = $('#email').val();
        if(password != cpassword){
            alert("Passwords are not equal");
            $('#cpassword').css('border','1px solid red');
        }else{
             $.ajax({
                type    :'POST',
                url     :'http://localhost/tmc/includes/ajax-signup.php',
                data    : {password:password,username:username,email:email},
                success : function(msg){
                    alert(msg);
                },                  
            });
        }
        //$("#submit").hide();
    });
```